# TextInputMask for only positive numbers

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, masking

In my app I want user to enter 2 digit number.

```
<TextInputMask
      placeholder="00" 
      ref={'Text2'}
      type={'only-numbers'} 
      maxLength={2}
      style = {styles.input2}
/>
```

However, user can press '-' (minus sign). How can I avoid this? 
I already tried adding **options={{mask : '999'}}**.

Comment: What library are you using for TextInputMask?  That component isn't part of the standard library

Comment: import {TextInputMask} from 'react-native-masked-text';

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could do a few things.  You could simply ignore any non-numeric inputs (this might help if people are going to paste values in) or you could mark the input as invalid.

This works for me for ignoring/swallowing the minus sign:

```
<TextInputMask
  placeholder="00"
  ref={'Text2'}
  type={'custom'}
  maxLength={2}
  keyboardType="numeric"
  style={styles.input}
  options={{
    mask: '99',
    translation: { '9': val => val === '-' ? null : val }
  }}
/>
```

It still allows the `.` but you could just expand the function to check for that also.